# Sync Azure Easy tables with sql database

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to sync an Azure easy tables with the SQL Database? I need to show data on android app from the SQL DB but the only way I found to do that is to use App service and Azure easy tables.

Answer (score 2):

Easy table will be created only if you select `Node.js` as Azure App backend.

[image: Node.Js Backend option]

Anyway, the created database will be saved on the selected **SQL Server**. No need to Sync it. Easy Table is just a visual table in Azure Platform. But the **Database** and the **Table** will get saved in SQL Database.Check the SQL server that you selected while creating the Azure App.

[image: Easy Table]

Above image is the Easy Table and the Below image is SQL Database.

[image: SQL Database]

And to show the data in Android you can use REST API to pull Data from Database. REST API can be created using **ASP.Net WebApi** Project in Visual Studio.

I hope answer might help you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to sync an Azure easy tables with the SQL Database?

As Nandhakumar Appusamy mentioned that Easy tables works with Node.js backend. Additionally, for adding new table APIs against your existing tables from your SQL Database, you need to navigate to the 'MOBILE > Easy Tables' blade and click **Add** button for adding your new table or existing table with the same name. When adding tables via Easy Tables, it would help you to build your Node.js backend for your added tables automatically. You could leverage "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > App Service Editor (Preview)" to check your backend as follows:

[image]

Moreover, here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

[Azure Mobile Apps Table Interface](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/)

[Download and run the Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started#download-and-run-the-android-app)

[How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library)